# hadoop's gzip different from tar -zvcf?

Tags: hadoop, gzip

The question is exactly this:

1. I create a text file and compress it with `tar -cxzf`. The file's name is `part-r-0000.gz`
2. Put the file on hdfs with `hadoop fs -put source dest`, hadoop's version is 0.20.2-cdh
3. Try to view the file with `hadoop fs -text part-r-0000.gz` and I found that shows garbled.

I wonder if there are different versions of gz compression?

Comment: I　think it should be tar -cvzf not -cxzf

Comment: were you able to read the part-r-0000 file before creating the tar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS browser does not support reading gzip files. It will show as garbled text on the browser. There is no problem with gzip. Though your command definitely is fishy. c is for create x for extract.

Hadoop supports file compression. Here is a link which explains well : [Compression](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/)

Answer (score 0):

command `tar`is error:
`-c Create  -x Extract`
sample:

- tar -czf ... -> create tgz file
- tar -xzf ... -> extract tgz file